# Array of Colors error. Bug?

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, colors

K. I'm getting stuck here.

I'm trying to make an array with different color values.

My problem is that when I do...
`teamColor[i] = currentColor`... all color values in my array turn into the currentColor.

(I would upload more code, but that would be a massive mess, considering that I have code everywhere with references from movie clips that are as far as 3 layers deep. HOWEVER, this would be irrelevant anyways (probably), because I tested this with color values on my main timeline, without any references to or from anything deeply nested)

I'm GUESSING that this is just some horrible bug, but if it's not (and I hope it isn't), please guide me in what to do to fix this problem.

I would like to add that I tried adding strings in there and that the strings remained their original, intended, value, while the color exhibited the same phenomenon.

***[Partially resolved]***: 
     I changed my code by creating separate variables for each color instead of  putting the variables into an array (not what I really wanted to do, but it works). My code looks like this: 
`

```
if (teamColor != 0)
{
    this["team"+teamColor+"Color"] = new ColorTransform(0,0,0,1,currentColor.redOffset,currentColor.greenOffset,currentColor.blueOffset,0)
    teamColor = 0
    namebox.addboxes()//function in a movieclip
}`
```

teamColor is now an int that is changed based on which box a user clicks from a movie clip that has a dynamically generated name, based off of what the variable value in a loop was when it was created. (E.G: 'tempboxname[ttns].name = i;') 
teamColor is then equal to that name when the user clicks it.

I have another movieclip with colors in it and the above function is called to check if any teamColor change has occurred, and if it has, act accordingly. (The idea of having teamColor equal to 0 is so that if the user clicks twice, nothing changes. I other conditionals for other colors, all within the same function). 
That is how I fixed me code.
It's not what I wanted, because it's not an array (meaning a seemingly infinite number of teamColors, and thus, teams) but it'll do for me. If anyone has any suggestions, feel free to suggest.

Comment: Is this in a `for` statement? Could you post the surrounding code?

Answer (score 2):

I'm no ActionScript wiz, but what it looks like to me is that currentColor is an object that is being passed into the array by reference. This means that all array entries that you assigned currentColor will be pointing at the same currentColor object, not a copy. My advice is to make a copy and then assign that into the array.

It would be much better if you could give me more code to look at. For instance, the loop that contains that code segment would be nice. If I find a different error I'll edit my answer.

Comment: By reference? You mean that teamColor[i] is just another way of saying currentColor in this case? That would obviously explain why it wasn't working. 

I do want to add that I DID get this working, but it's lack luster and boring. I just created 10 variables (the max number of teams) and added this code:
if (teamColor != 0)
 {
  this["team"+teamColor+"Color"] = new ColorTransform(0,0,0,1,currentColor.redOffset,currentColor.greenOffset,currentColor.blueOffset,0)
  teamColor = 0
  namebox.addboxes()
 }.
This function is part of a larger function that is activated with a stage-wide mouse_down.

Comment: @Exyphrius That is exactly what i meant (teamColor[i] is just another way of saying currentColor). You don't need to do this with 10 variables if you just make a copy of the color to assign into the array.

Answer (score 0):

here i'm creating and then adding simple 0xRRGGBB color objects into a vector.  the color objects are then parsed into 0xRRGGBB hexadecimal strings and traced.

certainly it's not exactly what your looking for, but hopefully it will help you.

```
var red:uint = 0xFF0000;
var green:uint = 0x00FF00;
var blue:uint = 0x0000FF;

var colors:Vector.<uint> = new Vector.<uint>()
colors.push(red, green, blue);

for each    (var color:uint in colors)
            {
            var output:String = color.toString(16);

            while   (output.length < 6)
                    output = "0" + output;

            trace("0x" + output.toUpperCase());
            }
```

Output:

```
//0xFF0000
//0x00FF00
//0x0000FF
```